# Hello World Kernel Module Invalid Format

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am currently trying to run my Hello World Kernel Module but I am struggling a bit and I do not know why.

First of all

uname -r

```
2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64
```

My Hello.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
static int __init hello_start(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr.\n");
}
module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

My Makefile

```
obj-m += hello.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` clean
```

Error message when running

```
$ sudo insmod ./hello.ko
insmod: error inserting './hello.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

dmesg output

```
hello: no symbol version for module_layout
```

files in folder

```
hello.c  hello.ko  hello.ko.unsigned  hello.mod.c  hello.mod.o  hello.o  include  Makefile  modules.order  Module.symvers
```

What is needed to insert this module and complete my further work?

Comment: I suspect you have to sign your module first. Possibly it could be done via `make modules_install`

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to insert the module in a kernel whose version is identical to the headers you're making against?

Comment: Problem solved. the gcc version for compiling the kernel and the module was not the same. Kernel compile 4.4.7, module compile 4.8.2